# How UAC Facility center on Earth also got infected?

Tags: plot-explanation, doom-2005

In Doom (2005), On Mars, at a UAC Research Facility, scientists are attacked by monsters which are infected. One of the scientist send video message to Earth. After seeing this message on Earth, a team of eight Marines known as the RRTS went to Mars to kill the monsters.

After killing all the monsters, they returned to UAC facility on Earth.  But Team find that all humans there were dead.

How did the people on Earth also get infected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At one point one of the infected breaches the Ark portal room where Pinky is supposed to be keeping guard.

Instead of destroying the creature with a grenade, Pinky uses the Ark to return to Earth, apparently the creature follows.

Once there is kills or infects the personnel at the Earth end of the Ark portal facility.

> The surviving team realize that a Hell Knight has escaped through the Ark to the Earth due to Pinky's refusal to trigger a grenade Mac left with him to destroy the Ark.
>
> <sup>[IMDB Synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419706/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)</sup>